# Controlling changes in the navigation stack

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I want to be able to check for specific conditions when a user selects the "back" button from a navigation controller - then display an alert and stop the pop up the navigation stack from occurring.

I can get notified in the viewWillDissappear method that the pop is about to occur - but is there a mechanism to stop the pop from happening?

Comment: I know I could achieve the effect by replacing the default back button with my own button, and managing the pop myself.  I'm wondering if there is a way to achieve this without replacing the default navigation controller button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try subclassing UINavigationController and then override the popViewController method to include your logic.

```
- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

[edit to include an example]
http://www.hanspinckaers.com/custom-action-on-back-button-uinavigationcontroller

Cheers,
Rog