# Control exiting of view while tab bar item change and navigation button press actions

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I want to prevent one of my views from exiting when the user presses the top left navigation bar button as well as he changes the tab bar selection.My purpose is to show an alert and ask the user to save the data before exiting the view and act according to the user's choice.
I found an answer for preventing exiting of view in the case of left navigation bar button press action here :
[Controlling changes in the navigation stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230455/controlling-changes-in-the-navigation-stack).

But Is there any common way to do that which can be applied to both tab bar item change and top left navigation bar press actions? Also if not how to do both in the easiest way? Hope my explanation is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no single place you can take care of both.  For the tab bar, set your `UITabBarController`'s `delegate` to some class of yours (maybe your application delegate), and in that class implement the `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:` method to return NO when you don't want the user to change tabs.

Comment: But how to control that in AlertView button actions.I want to stay in the same view if the user clicks save.If he clicks cancel I have to proceed his selection.